# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < using Jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

What I tried

Request: Jsonp
Response: returned XML Response 200.
Cross Domain Request that's why used data type: jsonp

Script code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    type: "POST", /* or type:"GET" or type:"PUT" */
    data:myusername,
    crossDomain: true, 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        'name':myusername
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
    //});
});
```

Here AJAX response is XML.
But can someone tell how can I solved unexpected token problem.
Response is XML.

solution i found is third party request

```
 var urljson='cross-damin-url';


   var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + 
     encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + urljson + '"') + 
   '&format=xml&callback=?';


    $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
      console.log(data.results[0]);
       });
```

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: The response is XML, and you are trying to parse it as JSON. You expect that to work...why?

Comment: i m trying to parse xml not json

Comment: When you set the response data type to `json` or `jsonp` jquery will attempt to parse it as such for you. Which is failing with a parse error for reasons I hope are now obvious. Also note that jsonp is **inherently insecure**. If the cross domain resource doesn't have a CORS header, you may want to just pipe it through your own domain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you are asking". If you can edit it to be coherent I'll remove the vote. What I *think* you are asking is a combination of "How do I CORS ajax request?", "What do I do if a resource on another domain doesn't have a CORS header?", and "How do I parse an xml response from an ajax call?". Please ask a *single*, *clear* question.

Comment: can anyone suggest best way to get xml result with any error in cross domain request using js

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the line "dataType: 'jsonp'". Setting it this way the ajax call expect the result to be a jsonp (a json object wrapped as a params in a callback...) this is useful if you're doing a cross domain call (due to CORS). You have to set a "dataType: 'xml'"

**Edit**
considering the you have to do a CORS call, you have to change the output of the api, at least making something like

```
callbackName({value:'<your><xml>...</xml></your>'})
```

and parsing the xml from the string 
"callbackName" is the name of a function or method declared in the page which make the ajax call and which will parse the json from the api... for instance something like:

```
function callbackName(result) {
  console.log($.parseXML(result.value)); 
}
```

Comment: my requirement cros "dataType: 'xml' its stops when cros request

Comment: well, then you have to change the output of the api, at least making something like "callbackName({value:'... you xml ...'}) and parsing the xml from the string

P.s. "callbackName" is the name of a function or method declared in the page which make the ajax call and which will parse the json from the api... for instance something like 
function callbackName(result) { console.log(result.value); }

Comment: can you give some example im new to jsonp

Comment: @RobertoBisello I gave you a +1, but please note that jsonp is **inherently insecure** and recommending its use is... arguable.

Comment: @JaredSmith I agree, jsonp is not really secure, but I've not recommended the use of jsonp, I've found a solution for afeef's problem considering the given context... honestly I dont's see any other solution :(

Comment: problem still not solved,can some tell me how to get cross domain xml response without any errors

Comment: @afeef have you modified the result? which error do you have? can you give us an example link?

Comment: im getting same error that i have raised i tried like: url url&callback=processData  function callbackName(result) {
  console.log($.parseXML(result.value)); 
}

Answer (score 0):

JSON and XML are arbitrarily nested data-interchange formats. You take a (well-formed) string and convert it to a data structure based on the rules of the format. Their similarities stop there.

So you can't just parse XML as JSON, they have different rules for turning a string (like that returned by an HTTP request) into a data structure. Which is why you're getting an error.

Parsing XML with an XML parser (like the one built into every browser) instead of a JSON parser will not throw an error.

But your actual problem is that it's a cross-domain resource and the browser (for good reason) won't let you. If you need a cross-domain resource and you don't control it and it doesn't have a CORS header you have a few options:

1. Beg the entity that controls the resource to add a CORS Header
2. Pipe the resource through your domain.

To expand on option 2:

Your page requests the resource from your webserver, your webserver makes an http request to the cross-origin resource, and then sends the result back to the browser.

### About JSONP

JSONP was a hack invented before CORS to **bypass the browser's security model**. It was (meant) to be used by people who understood the risks, knew what they were doing and why. It involves potentially executing arbitrary third-party code on your page. Needless to say, that's bad.

Comment: hi jared does we need third party url (if server has not allowed cross domain true.)

Comment: @afeef then you'll have to do option 2 and fetch the data server-side and return it to the browser so it comes from your domain.